# Как делать резиновые блоки по высоте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Надо создать такую структуру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Левое изображения имеет 960x960 и занимает 50% экрана, т.е сам экран 1920 (960*2). Но как быть, если экран будет 1600, тогда изображения будет занимать так же 50% и будет иметь 800px однако высоту я не могу подогнать под ширину. Можно ли сделать что бы высота была равна ширине(без js)?

Comment: Можно использовать единицу измерения `vw`, которая составляет 1% от ширины. То есть `height: 50vw;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А как вам такое? Я задал переменной `gap` расстояние между grid-элементами.
Почему-то эта штука начинает нормально работать тут, только когда откроешь её на весь экран с открытой консолью разработчика (у меня Google Chrome).
В редакторе на компьютере - всё отлично, можете сами проверить
**UPD:** заметил, что если кликать на выполнить код(с закрытой консолью), то рандомно, в какой то момент нету полосы прокрутки по ширине, но чаще прокрутка есть

Поясню, что накалякал:

```css
:root {
  --gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: var(--gap);
    grid-template-rows: calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2);
    grid-template-columns: calc(50vw - var(--gap)) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2);
}
```

в `:root` я задаю переменную `--gap`, равную 10px, чтобы использовать для отступа между grid-элементами.
`.wrapper` задаю, что это grid-сетка `display: grid`
Задаю отступ в 10px между grid-элементами, используя ранее объявленную переменую `grid-gap: var(--gap)`
`grid-template-rows` отвечает за размер элементов по вертикали
`grid-template-rows: calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2)`
Нам нужно задать, что высота каждого элемента равна будет равна 1/4 от ширины экрана или `25vw`, но у нас также есть отступ в 10px между элементами по вертикали. Чтобы убрать эти 10px, нужно их вычесть из всех ширин, а точнее - первому и второму элементу по вертикали вычесть 10px/2, получится, что у каждого вычли по 5px, в сумме 10px.

`grid-template-columns` задаёт размер элементов по горизонтали
`grid-template-columns: calc(50vw - var(--gap)) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2)`
Первый элемент по ширине можно считать за два обычных по 1/4 от ширины экрана. всего у нас 2 отступа по 10px, в сумме 20px, значит, чтобы всё было ровно, надо из каждого элемента вычесть 5px, а точнее, из первого вычесть два раза по 5 px `calc(50vw - var(--gap))`, а из второго и третьего по 5px просто `calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2)`.

Первый элемент, чтобы был на всю высоту, нужно задать, что он начинается с первой линии `grid-row-start: 1` и заканчивается на начале третьей линии `grid-row-end: 3`

```css
.item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: black;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: var(--gap);
    grid-template-rows: calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2);
    grid-template-columns: calc(50vw - var(--gap)) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2) calc(25vw - var(--gap)/2);
}

.item {
    background-color: orange;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: black;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">I am Black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
</div>
```

Можно сделать также без отступов, тогда не надо будет ничего считать

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25vw 25vw;
    grid-template-columns: 50vw 25vw 25vw;
}

.item {
    background-color: orange;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: black;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #2e5fc1;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #2e5fc1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">I am Black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
    <div class="item">I am not black</div>
</div>
```

Вот этот вариант вроде работает в IE11. Вы можете использовать также [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/), чтобы добавить к своему коду нужные префиксы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper, .wrapper__2, .wrapper__3, .wrapper__4, .item {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper__2 {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    background-color: orange;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper__1 .item {
    background-color: black;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper__2 .item {
    height: 25vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.wrapper__3 .item:nth-child(1), 
.wrapper__4 .item:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #2e5fc1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="wrapper__1">
        <div class="item">I am Black</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__2">
        
        <div class="wrapper__3">
            <div class="item">I am not black</div>
            <div class="item">I am not black</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper__4">
            <div class="item">I am not black</div>
            <div class="item">I am not black</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Решение на CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block__left,
.wrp {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.block__left__ok,
.wrp__ok {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.wrp__ok {
  padding: 0;
}

.block__01,
.block__02,
.block__03,
.block__04 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.block__01__ok,
.block__02__ok,
.block__03__ok,
.block__04__ok {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.block__left__ok {
  background-color: red;
}

.block__01__ok {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block__02__ok {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.block__03__ok {
  background-color: green;
}

.block__04__ok {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__left">
  <div class="block__left__ok"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="wrp__ok">
    <div class="div block__01">
      <div class="div block__01__ok"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div block__02">
      <div class="div block__02__ok"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div block__03">
      <div class="div block__03__ok"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div block__04">
      <div class="div block__04__ok"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Решение на jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $('.block__left, .wrp').height($('.block__left, .wrp').width() / 1);
  $('.div').height($('.div').width() / 1);
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.block__left, .wrp').height($('.block__left, .wrp').width() / 1);
    $('.div').height($('.div').width() / 1);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block__left,
.wrp {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.div,
.block__01,
.block__02,
.block__03,
.block__04 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.block__left {
  background-color: red;
}

.block__01 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block__02 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.block__03 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block__04 {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block__left"></div>
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="div block__01"></div>
  <div class="div block__02"></div>
  <div class="div block__03"></div>
  <div class="div block__04"></div>
</div>
```